# Sort python list of dictionaries by key if key exists

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{"foo" : "bar", "myKey" : "one"}, 
{"foo" : "bar", "myKey" : "two"}, 
{"foo" : "bar", "yourKey" : "three"}]
```

I'd like to sort it by a key in the dictionary if it exists.

```
featured = sorted(filesToWrite, key=lambda k: k["myKey"])
```

This doesn't work if `"myKey"` doesn't exist.  **EDIT:** If `myKey` doesn't exist in the dictionary, I'd like it to appear at the end of the list.

I could loop through the list manually and do it myself but I'm sure there is a pythonic way to accomplish my goal without doing all that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
featured = sorted(filesToWrite, key=lambda k: ("myKey" not in k, k.get("myKey", None)))
```

Output:

```
[{'foo': 'bar', 'myKey': 'one'}, {'foo': 'bar', 'myKey': 'two'}, {'yourKey': 'three', 'foo': 'bar'}]
```

The magic happens in the key:

```
("myKey" in k, k.get("myKey", None)
```

Which is a two item tuple, like:

```
(True, "one")
```

Where the first element is True/False depending on whether or not the key is missing (True comes after False hence the `not`), and the second element is the value of said key, if it exists. If not, `None`. (that argument can be skipped, but I included it to be explicit)

Comment: confused.  I don't want yourKey at all...I just want anything without "myKey" should be at the end

Answer (score 1):

If you're really stuck (like I was, due to the structure of the data I was attempting to sort), you may want to break out of the lambda design, at least for diagnostic purposes.  Only when I applied the ["nonesorter" design shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12971697/5025060) did I receive a meaningful diagnostic from Python that showed me that the thing I was sorting wasn't what I thought it was.

More generally: the "lambda"s you see above are shorthand that can be replaced by a full method definition that you can step through line by line with a debugger.

Also, somewhat misleading to the neophyte is the label `key=` in Python's sort syntax.  This is not actually the name of a key field in the dictionary but rather a pointer to a function which will determine order, analogous to Perl's sort parameter called `SUBNAME`.

As [Python.org's Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html) describes it,

> The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a
>   single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes. This
>   technique is fast because the key function is called exactly once for
>   each input record.

Finally, note that as others have stated, None was a legal item for comparison in Python 2 whereas [with Python 3 attempting to compare to None generates a compiler exception.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-February/132355.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [{"foo" : "bar", "myKey" : "one"}, 
... {"foo" : "bar", "myKey" : "two"}, 
... {"foo" : "bar", "yourKey" : "three"}]
>>> 
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda d:("myKey" not in d, d.get("myKey")))
[{'foo': 'bar', 'myKey': 'one'}, {'foo': 'bar', 'myKey': 'two'}, {'yourKey': 'three', 'foo': 'bar'}]
```

Comment: No. This doesn't work for UTF-8 or non-string values. This unnecessarily relies on some behavior of sorted().

Comment: @IceArdor, Yes, I deleted the second way. Not sure what you mean about relying on the behaviour of `sorted`. It is documented behaviour afterall.

Comment: using `sorted(L, key=lambda d:d.get("myKey","\xff"))` relies on how sorted compares an ASCII string to a non-ASCII string or non-string. While my version of Jython happens to sort None and numbers before strings, that could change in future. I wouldn't personally want to chase down a bug to discover that the programmer relied on `sorted`'s interpretation of data type precedence.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
sorted((e for e in case if 'myKey' in e), key=lambda x: x['myKey']) + [e for e in case if 'myKey' not in e]
```

...?

Assuming the 'case' variable holds the list of dicts you just mentioned. I also assume that if the key is not present, it should be ignored, which seems to make sense.

Comment: This requires looping through the dict twice. Inefficient.