# Python: Sort Two Lists Based On First With None Types

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, nonetype

So I have two lists:

```
keys   = ['Z', 'X', None, None]
values = [ 0 ,  1 , None, None]
```

I need to be able to take these two lists and sorted them based on the keys value, and then return it to themselves. Ideally, the output would be:

```
keys   = ['X', 'Z', None, None]
values = [ 1 ,  0 , None, None]
```

What I'm trying here is:

```
self.keys, self.values = (list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(self.keys, 
                          self.values), key=lambda pair: pair[0])))
```

This works great, except that it gives me the error of:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < str()
```

How can I have None be sorted using this method? Is there a better method then what I'm trying?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971631/sorting-list-by-an-attribute-that-can-be-none

Comment: Is `None` supposed to be greater than everything?

Comment: @LauroMoura That question is close, but it wasn't using the method I was trying to implement.

Comment: @timgeb That'd be correct, None should always stay at the end of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a condition to your key for `sorted`

```
keys, values = (list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(keys, values), key=lambda pair: pair[0] if pair[0] is not None else 'temp')))
```

doing so maps 'temp' to any None value in your list and in the order of comparison for sorted 'temp' is greater than 'X'. uppercase alphabets are smaller than lowercase

```
>>> 'temp' < 'X'
False
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The linked question has some viable approaches, but I think misses out on my preferred one, which is to sort on a *tuple* key instead of a scalar.  That way we can make sure that we're only ever comparing comparable quantities.

For example:

```
>>> list(zip(keys, values))
[('Z', 0), ('X', 1), (None, None), (None, None)]
>>> sorted(zip(keys, values),key=lambda x: (x[0] is None, x[0]))
[('X', 1), ('Z', 0), (None, None), (None, None)]
```

This works because for each pair, we get a tuple of a bool and a string:

```
>>> for pair in zip(keys, values):
...     print(pair, (pair[0] is None, pair[0]))
...     
('Z', 0) (False, 'Z')
('X', 1) (False, 'X')
(None, None) (True, None)
(None, None) (True, None)
```

Because of how tuple comparison works, we'll only ever have to compare within the True or the False groups, so None will never be compared to a string.  And since False < True, we'll get the None pairs at the end.

Comment: I like this implementation, and I am very tempted to vote it the correct answer. However, I don't want to change the representation of keys and values from being two separate lists. If I didn't have that requirement, your answer would be the way to go.

Comment: @Avairhn: erm, you don't need to.  Just like in your original code you write `sorted(zip(self.keys, self.values), key=lambda pair: pair[0])`, you could instead use the above key function.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have your sort key function to be consistent on return value (if not, you should), just modify it like `lambda pair: pair[0] or ""`. It will return `""` on `(None, <WHATEVER>)`.

Otherwise please define if `None > "1"` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to have some object that is never lesser than any other object, and use that for comparison in case you encounter `None`.

```
>>> def sortkey(pair):
...     if pair[0] is not None:
...         return pair[0]
...     return type('', (object,), {'__lt__': lambda x,y: False})()
... 
>>> keys   = ['Z', 'X', None, None]
>>> values = [ 0 ,  1 , None, None]
>>> k, v = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(keys, values), key=sortkey)))
>>> k
['X', 'Z', None, None]
>>> v
[1, 0, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would involve defining your own key

```
sort_fxn = lambda pair: '' if pair[0] is None else pair[0] 
list(zip(*sorted(zip(keys, values), key=sort_fxn)))
```

The None values are not positioned at the end of the sort but the other keys are sorted:

```
[(None, None, 'X', 'Z'), (None, None, 1, 0)]
```

---

If having the None values is critical to your sorting you could encode all your strings into bytes and use byte array comparison:

```
sort_fxn = lambda pair: bytes([255]) if pair[0] is None else pair[0].encode('utf-8')
```

Note: this does take twice as long to sort with because of the ordering. (3 vs 1.5 microseconds) If you're worried about that kind of optimization.