# Sort a list of tuples with None values in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

> In Python 3 the ordering comparison operators (<, <=, >=, >) raise a
>   TypeError exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural
>   ordering

This change in comparison creates difficulties to order a list of tuples, if there exist None values.

**In Python 2:**

```
>>> unordered_list = [('3', '1', None), ('3','1', '4'), ('3', '1', None)]
>>> sorted(unordered_list, reverse=True)

[('3', '1', '4'), ('3', '1', None), ('3', '1', None)]
```

**In Python 3:**

```
>>> unordered_list = [('3', '1', None), ('3','1', '4'), ('3', '1', None)]
>>> sorted(unordered_list, reverse=True)

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < NoneType()
```

Do you have any idea how to have the same behavior with Python 2 an elegant way?

**NOTE:** In the above examples I have integers, but it's only an example. The elements of the tuples will have the same type and they could be any type.

```
ex.2 [('test3','test1', 'test4'), ('test3', 'test1', None)]
ex.3 [( 3, 1, 4), (3, 1, None)]
ex.4 [( 3.1, 1.1, 4.1), (3.1, 1.1, None)]
```

Comment: Have fun re-implementing the old [comparison rules](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) :-P

Comment: *"In the above examples I have integers"* - No you don't. Those are strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list by an attribute that can be None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971631/sorting-list-by-an-attribute-that-can-be-none)

Comment: The elegant way is not to have any ``None`` values in your list. Is there a reason why you are required to have this mixed data in the first place?

Comment: If `None` is the only problem, I guess you could sort with `key=lambda t: [(v is None, v) for v in t]`.

Comment: Yes @MisterMiyagi I know that this is the root of the problem but I can avoid them in my application because are meaningful values in my domain and I can't replace them with zeros or empty strings.

Comment: A way could be writing a function that compares tuples (or other objects) of disparate types, then using `functools.cmp_to_key(custom_cmp)` wherever you need to in functions that require a key. @ggeop

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use a custom key function to translate all `None`s to an empty string, eg:

```
sorted(unordered_list, key=lambda L: tuple(el or '' for el in L), reverse=True)
```

Which'll give you:

```
[('3', '1', '4'), ('3', '1', None), ('3', '1', None)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!But this answer covers only the case which we have strings. I want a generic solution, for other types :-)

Comment: @ggeop You can incorporate a `if-else` in your tuple comprehension if the values is `None` store `float('-inf')`

Comment: @ggeop there isn't really a generic case... you can do what Ch3steR has suggested and use negative/positive inf. floats if you know you've got  numbers to compare against, but then that'll break your example with strings...

Comment: I know that is difficult, thats the reason for the question :-) I have add more examples in the question in order to be more clear.

Comment: @ggeop difficult is one way of describing it... what about `[('bob', '1', 'x'), (None, 1, 3), (3.0, '1', None)]` ?

Comment: I would like to have the same behavior with Python2. Ok your example its not meaningful, and I don't have this case with mixed types. I will re-edit my question in order to be more clear

Comment: @ggeop thanks... can I ask why you want the same behaviour as Py2 though? It's a kind of mistake it ever had that behaviour (hence it's gone now) and the ordering is pretty meaningless anyway

Comment: Agreed. Doesn't make sense to order None in any way. If anything leaving it to a custom key to handle it in whichever way is wanted seems like the only sensible option

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to define a custom function as a `key` prior to sorting, catching the `TypeError`.
Also note that you want to cast the numerical values to `int` or `float`, otherwise the ordering process will be [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

```
def handle_none(t):
    out = tuple()
    for i in t:
        try:
            out += (float(i),)
        except TypeError:
            out += (-float('inf'),) 
    return out
```

---

For the first case:

```
unordered_list = [('3', '1', '4'), ('3', '1', None), ('3', '1', None)]

sorted(unordered_list, key=handle_none, reverse=True)
# [('3', '1', '4'), ('3', '1', None), ('3', '1', None)]
```

Another example:

```
unordered_list = [( 3.1, 1.1, 4.1), ( 3.1, 1.1, 7.1), (3.1, 1.1, None), ( 3.1, 1.1, 8.1)]

sorted(unordered_list, key=handle_none, reverse=True)
# [(3.1, 1.1, 8.1), (3.1, 1.1, 7.1), (3.1, 1.1, 4.1), (3.1, 1.1, None)]
```