# Sorting Dictionary Tuple Keys containing None and String in Python 3

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Below code is working in python 2 but its breaking in python 3, could you please help

```
destObj={('SVC_157', None):'05-04-2022', ('SVC_157', 'V1.0'):'06-07-2022'}

for (rel, ver) in sorted(destObj.keys()):
    print((rel, ver))
```

**Please note**: position of None is not fixed, it may vary if release is having more components for ex like below,
('SVC_157', 'SMU', 'Windows 10 ARM64', None )

FYI: Its not duplicate of [Sorting list by an attribute that can be None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971631/sorting-list-by-an-attribute-that-can-be-none)

Comment: The problem is that comparison against `None` in Python 3 throws an exception

Comment: @joanis I found the duplicate and close the question, so I want to avoid any possible conflict of interest

Comment: But reading the duplicate, it's not a perfect duplicate. If OP is not a reasonably advanced Python programmer, they might not know how to apply that solution to a tuple that might contain None, rather than to elements that might be None themselves. Maybe put the lambda expression from your deleted answer in a comment here?

Comment: I've already seen that post, I know it seems similar but its different

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` parameter as below, to mimic the Python 2 behavior:

```
destObj = {('SVC_157', None): '05-04-2022', ('SVC_157', 'V1.0'): '06-07-2022'}

def key(t):
    return tuple(e or "" for e in t)

for (rel, ver) in sorted(destObj.keys(), key=key):
    print((rel, ver))
```

**Output**

```
('SVC_157', None)
('SVC_157', 'V1.0')
```

If you have tuples of multiple sizes, the unpacking in the for loop is not going to work, do the following instead:

```
destObj = {('SVC_157', 'SMU', 'Windows 10 ARM64', None): '05-04-2022', ('SVC_157', 'V1.0'): '06-07-2022'}

def key(t):
    return tuple(e or "" for e in t)

for tup in sorted(destObj.keys(), key=key):
    print(tup)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but for below its not working
destObj = {
('SVC_157', 'SMU', 'Windows 10 ARM64', None ):'05-04-2022',
 ('SVC_157', 'V1.0'): '06-07-2022'
}

Comment: @Yash See the update in the question

Comment: Thank you so much @Dani Mesejo for your help,  it worked!